# Django-channels: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'profile'

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-channels

So I have my websockets in consumers, I did in consumers that when the websocket is receive it will update with +1 a FloatField in my models, the problem is that I dont know why is not working, here is my code:

models.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

class ProfileImage(models.Model):
    """
    Profile model
    """
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        verbose_name=_('User'),
        to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        related_name='profile',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_image')
    notifications = models.FloatField(default='0')
```

consumers.py:

```
async def websocket_receive(self, event):
    # when a message is received from the websocket
    print("receive", event)

    # update the message notification badge val
    other_user = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['username']
    
    notification = other_user.profile.objects.get(pk=1)
    notification.notifications = +1
    notification.save()
```

the problem is that when a websocket is receive it doesn´t update the floatfield value and it give me this error:

```
    notification = other_user.profile.objects.get(pk=1)
    AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'profile'
```

does anybody know what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a string into the variable `other_user`. then trying to access your user model through a string object. First of all, you need to use the non-static reference to the class model you setup in django `models.py`. Then, use the username you saved into the variable to search the database.

Comment: How can I make a non-static reference?

Comment: refer to the class used to create the model. In this case 'ProfileImage'. To get any 'ProfileImage' object saved to the database it should be something like 'ProfileImage.objects.get(pk=primaryKeyOfTheDesiredProfile)'. I would consider making one Profile model and making the Profileimage a field within the model. Once you access this model using the nonstatic reference and primary key, you can save that to say a variable named 'profile'. then you can call any field you made within , say 'profile.profileimage'